# ubuntu 32 bit sourceguardian error

Tags: ubuntu

I have configured in Ubuntu 32bit and When I run my PHP project in LAMP Environment, it gives below error :

`Fatal error: SourceGuardian Loader - Protected script header checksum error. The file has been modified. Install the original unmodified file or contact the script author to get the original file. Error code [17] in /var/www/projectname/index.php on line 3`

When I disable all errors on website, it goes blank nothing comes just a blank page.

Any help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you trying to Source Guardian your project? Or are you using a Source Guardian protected script?

It looks like your PHP project is checking to see if a script has been modified. Are you using a "paid for" script anywhere in your project, and if so.. what is it (this may shed some light on your troubles)? Try reverting back to the original script that you brought.

"Protect PHP Scripts using the SourceGuardian for PHP Encoder. We encode your PHP code by compiling the PHP source code into a binary bytecode format, which is then supplemented an encryption layer. You can use obfuscation of several levels of complexity to add another protection layer. No changes can be made to the protected scripts once they have been encoded, which adds an additional security level and any changes to an encoded file will make it unusable. " - http://www.sourceguardian.com/protect_php_scripts.html

If you need to modify the code in some way, go back to the place where you brought the script and they may be able to help you.

If its your script (and you are using source guardian to protect it), make sure you are working on the original unprotected source, then run the modified source through Source Guardian again when you are ready to publish.

Hope this helps solve your problem:-)